# Can I disable ad-ons from appearing on my website by modifying my xhtml code?

Tags: xhtml

I developed a website for my husband’s company and just discovered that when I view these pages on my browser, ad-ons cause certain words to be underlined that link to pop-ups that direct users to other sites (potentially our competition).  My research has turned up only ways to turn ad-ons off on my browser, but I’d like to fix my html (XHTML 1.0 Transitional) so that customers who view our pages don’t see these advertisements.  Is there some way to modify the xhtml to disable ad-ons on a page by page basis?

Comment: no. All you can do is stop installing spyware and other malware in your browser. Nothing you can do to your site can prevent these add-ons from looking at the content.

Comment: It's a fair question, but the answer is no. Users with this problem have let their browser be hijacked by the malware, the problem needs to be solved on their end.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the add-on is modifying your html as it's displayed to the browser (likely), you could use jquery to run after your page is loaded (and after add-ons run, so use a timer), to search the page for all links to external sites and if they're not links you put in (maybe identified by class), then remove them.

A bit of a cat and mouse game, but since the add-ons are not specifically targeted to your site, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing the site using a different computer? I fix computers all the time and have noticed malware that makes advertising links on websites that have nothing to do with the malware. I would recommend scanning your computer, there are plenty of freeware programs and most anti-virus programs have a free version (AVG, Avast, Comodo, etc) though I would avoid McAffe, Norton and Windows Defender.

You said browser, but you did not specify *which* browser. In Firefox go to Tools menu at the top (you may have to press ALT or click on a big goofy combined menu at the top-right) or if you can't find the Addons menu press CTRL+SHIFT+a and then remove/disable anything that you did NOT intentionally install.

Since your question has limited scope of details please reply if this doesn't help/help enough and we can work on making sure you can ask the question in a way that can get you answers faster.